# ComplexFilterPart Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'AND' PHP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, php

I'm getting an error trying to pass a ComplexFilterPart. Everything appears to be correct. I did a var_dump and everything appears to be in order, but I cannot figure out why I'm getting this error.

I saw this thread from a few years ago that never got answered. I tried Kelly's suggestion, but that doesn't work either, it gives a 500 server error to my ajax call. So I think the way the code is written is right, I just can't figure out where this error is coming from or why. Here is the var_dump

```
object(SoapVar)[20]
  public 'enc_type' => int 301
  public 'enc_value' => 
    object(NJ_ComplexFilter)[19]
      public 'LeftOperand' => 
        object(NJ_SimpleFilter)[17]
          public 'Property' => string 'Name' (length=4)
          public 'SimpleOperator' => string 'like' (length=4)
          public 'Value' => string 'test' (length=4)
          public 'DateValue' => null
      public 'LogicalOperator' => string 'AND' (length=3)
      public 'RightOperand' => 
        object(NJ_SimpleFilter)[18]
          public 'Property' => string 'Subject' (length=7)
          public 'SimpleOperator' => string 'like' (length=4)
          public 'Value' => string 'another' (length=7)
          public 'DateValue' => null
      public 'AdditionalOperands' => null
  public 'enc_stype' => string 'ComplexFilterPart' (length=17)
  public 'enc_ns' => string 'http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI' (length=38)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post helped me solve the issue. Both SimpleFilterParts need to be SOAP encoded.

[Create A Complex Filter Part using ExactTarget PHP API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30922/create-a-complex-filter-part-using-exacttarget-php-api?rq=1)